# Asynchronicity in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question about asynchronicity in Javascript. From what I've been able to read up on about is that Javascript only uses one thread but is able to handle events asynchronously.

I have the following code:

```
game.next();
this.autopilot();
```

Now, I need the function `game.next` to finish before the `this.autopilot` function is called. Does Javascript actually wait until `game.next` is finished or does it run `this.autopilot` istantly?

If it does, does a callback solve the problem?

The next function with a callback:

```
Game.prototype.next = function(callback) {
    // Code

    if(callback !== undefined) {
        callback();
    }
};
```

The calling function using that callback:

```
game.next(function() {
    this.autopilot();
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Well, that depends on wether your `// Code` does something asynchronous or not and you wanted *that* to "finish"…

Comment: Well if `// CODE` does something async then the `callback` there does not help because the async part would be executed after the `callback` if it looks that way. The callback needs to be called out of the async part.

Comment: I see, so if all code in `// Code` returns when they're fully finished, I don't really need a callback? It computes some stuff and goes over a list of other objects calling functions, but no asynchronous code is run.

Comment: Then it's fine, synchronous code will run sequentially as you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a callback to make sure `game.next()` finishes before `this.autopilot()`. But there is a trick: you just cannot paste some callback after whatever code. Whether or not you need to implement a callback depends on whether `game.next()` function is asynchronous.

Example of a synchronous function that doesn't need a callback:

```
function next() {
   Game.x += 1;
}
```

Example of an asynchronous function that needs a callback to preserve the execution order:

```
function next(callback) {
   window.setTimeout(function() {
       if(callback !== undefined) { /* etc. */ }
   }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Probably it would be better to stay with vanilla js and use `setTimeout` with a value of `0` instead of using jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `game.next()` must return before `this.autopilot()` is called.

However, it is possible that `game.next()` starts an asynchronous process (e.g., an Ajax call) and returns before the process completes. If you want to defer execution of `this.autopilot()` until that process is complete, then you would need some sort of callback mechanism. `game.next()` would have to pass the callback function on to whatever asynchronous processing was taking place. (Executing the call-back just before returning—as you suggest in your question—would be wrong, as this would also happen before the asynchronous process completed.)